# (Slang) Way's to say: What's Up/How's It Going

Tags: translation

I know:

- 最近どうですか？
- 最近どう？

to ask, `what's up?`/`how's it going?`.

what other ways are they to say *what's up?* or *how's it going?*

**Slang-y** ways would be nice to know too.

Comment: 最近ですか >> typo for 最近どうですか, no?

Comment: @Choko Edited it! Good catch.

Comment: If by slangy you mean 方言 (Dialects) you are looking for well over 100 different phrases. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 7):

Casual (to your friend):

- 元気？
- 元気にしてる？
- 最近どう？
- 調子はどう？

A bit polite (to your colleague):

- 元気ですか？
- 最近どうですか？
- 調子はどうですか？

Polite, formal:

- お元気ですか？
- 調子はいかがですか？
- ご機嫌いかがですか？ (rare; mainly used in fiction by nobles)

Slangy, masculine but respectful (e.g. to a senior in your sport team):

- 元気っすか？
- 調子どっすか？

Comment: what would hoodlums likely say?

Comment: Western-style young gangsters would perhaps say 「よう、最近どうよ？」「元気か？」 in translated works. Japanese traditional *yakuza* would say differently, but I'm not good at their speech.

Comment: never forget my favorite--おっす(super slangy, also considered masculine), also ちわっす

Comment: @MichaelChirico おっす is not asking anything to the listener. If we could include greetings like "hey" "yo", the list would surely be much longer.

Comment: I would argue that we should. "what's up" is only obliquely a question to me in english, as I very rarely give/expect/receive an answer. and in fact it can be reciprocated with another (empty) question. perhaps this was not OPs intent... but I always shy away from direct translation anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the おっす, MichaelChirico. I was going to ask if people still used it. It's been a decade since I lived in Japan, and since then I've seen people online say you sound like a douchebag if you use おっす. I don't know, though, but I am a douchebag, so maybe I should keep saying it :)

And I agree with you about おっす being appropriate here. "What's up?" in English is more or less rhetorical. At least in American English, no answer other than "oh, nothing much" is acceptable anyway. You're not actually asking for a litany of physical ailments! It's just another way of saying "hello."